# Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_30 has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run my app in Android Studio, and it shows this error - **Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_30 has terminated.** Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you try doing 'wipe data' to the emulator in AVD manager?

Comment: no, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Try 'wipe data' on the emulator in AVD manager.
To enter the AVD manager click on its button in the toolbar:
[image]

Then, select 'wipe data' to format the emulator:
[image]

Comment: Maybe check if there are any updates to the emulator (in SDK manager)

Comment: probably, problem is in directory

Comment: It works! Problem was in directory!

Comment: @TimurJuten What do you mean by the problem in the directory?

Answer (score -1):

First check your updates
Then Go to system properties and check your processor is Intel Core i5 CPU. 4GB of RAM
minimum processor for android emulator Intel Core i5 CPU. 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).