# Why won't the Android emulator run on macOS 10.14 Mojave or earlier?

Tags: android, emulation

Hopefully someone can help me with the following problem:

I installed Android Studio (Artic Fox, 2020.3.1. patch 3) on an fairly old MBP (mid 2012, i7, 16G, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB, Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB, High Sierra 10.13.6)

When i want to run my first app i get this message:

**Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_30 has terminated.**

I searched on Stackoverflow for solutions and i found the following:

[Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_30 has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866264/error-while-waiting-for-device-the-emulator-process-for-avd-pixel-3a-api-30-has)

[Emulator always crashes with error "Error While waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD has terminated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68640302/emulator-always-crashes-with-error-error-while-waiting-for-device-the-emulator)

But both solutions did't work for me.

Can someone point me to the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Did the emulator ever start OK? You might need to run the Intel HAXM installer. Also try starting an Android Virtual Device from the AVD manager window. If that fails, it might say least provide some error info.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and pointing me in the right direction!

I already tried the two solutions you suggested. That did't work unfortunately :-( But during my quest i came across this post: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator-on-macos-6e611d2d2bcb

And... this did it for me. So it cost me 2 days but thanks to you and Arthur Wilton i was able to get the (downgraded) emulator to work!

For all who face the same problem i hope the post of Artur Wilton will save you your time.

Comment: Manolo, that's great news. Do you want to summarize that post's lessons in an answer here or let someone else do that? Key points: Running `emulator -avd <AVD_NAME>` gets a useful error message, in this case about a missing dynamic library which ultimately means Arctic Fox's emulator requires macOS 10.15 Catalina. The post offers a way to downgrade the emulator. Another approach of course would be to upgrade macOS (if you don't rely on any 32-bit apps). There's also room for bug reports on incompatibility and the buried error info.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize from [Arthur Wilton's medium post](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator-on-macos-6e611d2d2bcb):

- **Recent versions of the Android emulator won't run on macOS before 10.15 Catalina**. The AVD Manager alert might read, *"The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 was killed."*
  Arthur encountered this problem with emulator version 30.5.3.0.
  As of this writing, the current release is 31.1.4.0.
- Launching the emulator from Android Studio **doesn't reveal error info** but in this case it's because the new emulator requires the `IOUSBHost` library that Apple introduced in macOS 10.15.
- You can **get error messages** and other information from the Android emulator from the command line:
  `emulator -version`
  `emulator -list-avds`
  `emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29` # try to run the named AVD
  (The emulator is typically installed in `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator` on macOS. It might not be on your shell path.)
- An obvious solution is to **upgrade to macOS 10.15 Catalina or later**. If you can't do that (staying on Mojave in order to run 32-bit apps?), **Arthur's workaround is to download Android Emulator 3.4.5** from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-7140946.zip, install it by unzipping it into `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`, then editing the `<revision>` info in `package.xml` to trick Android Studio into thinking you have the latest emulator installed. Otherwise it'll try to upgrade it.